# iOS app still using old MSE favicon

Tags: bug, meta, ios-app, favicon

Like it or not, Meta Stack Exchange favicon was changed recently to [image], however in the app the old icon is still showing:

> [image]

Can it please be updated?

Comment: It's actually correct for me now though. Try force quitting the app?

Comment: @mhlester oh, missed your report! Anyway still showing old icon even after force quitting.

Comment: [strange...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VnUDO.jpg)

Comment: @mhlester yup. Just to be sure, how you "force quit" exactly? :)

Comment: Double click home button for app switching, then swipe up on the SE app so it leaves the top of screen. Then launch it again

Comment: @mhlester yeah, exactly what I did. Maybe server side cache of some sort...

Comment: Must be. Enjoy the old icon while it lasts!

Comment: @mhlester oh, I enjoy! ;)